# Laravel 4 Pagination not working (ErrorException)

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I've searched for all solutions to implement pagination successfully, but nothing I've found worked. I'm new to Laravel so I have maybe only one of those basic misunderstandings.

I have created it like it is described in the current documentation. And I get the first page successfully, exactly the content i need, but when i try to use the pagination, clicking on the "next"-arrow, I get an error message:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: reviews (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\search.blade.php)
```

I know what this generally means but absolutely no idea how to solve this.

This is the form in the view file:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search', 'class' => 'search', 'method' =>'GET')) }}
{{ Form::text('title') }}
{{ Form::submit('Suche')}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here is my routes configuration:

```
Route::any('/search', array('uses' => 'HomeController@search'));
```

Here is my function in the HomeController:

```
public function search() {
    $input = Input::get('title');
    if($input && $input != ''){
        $games = DB::table('games')->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$input%")->get();
        foreach ($games as $game) {
            $reviews = DB::table('reviews')->whereGame_id($game->id)->paginate(3);
        }
    }
    return View::make('search', compact('reviews', 'input', 'games'));
}
```

Here is the view-code of the search.blade.php view, which displays the results:

```
@section('content')
<h2>Suchergebnisse</h2>
    @foreach ($reviews as $review)
        @foreach ($games as $game)
            @if ($game->id == $review->game_id)
                <h3> {{ $game->name }} </h3>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        <p>{{ (preg_replace('/\n/i', '<br/>', $review->body)) }}</p>
    @endforeach
{{ $reviews->appends(array('term' => $input))->links() }}
@stop
```

I thank you beforehand if someone knows why Laravel has a problem with this solution.

**Edit:** 
I've changed the compact-statement and replaced it with an simple array, just like that:

```
return View::make('search', array('reviews' => $reviews, 'input' => $input, 'games' => $games));
```

Then I've added `global $games; global $reviews;` to the Controller, so the Error "Undefined variable: reviews" disappeared. Now I've got the following message, but only on page 2, page 1 works fine:

```
ErrorException

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\search.blade.php)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `compact` rather just creating an array?

Comment: i've just replaced that 'compact' with a normal array, so i have: `return View::make('search', array('reviews' => $reviews, 'input' => $input, 'games' => $games));` Then I've added `global $games; global $reviews;` to the controller. Now the Error changes, it says now:  `ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\search.blade.php)``

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are doing this

```
foreach ($games as $game) {
    // $reviews is being updated every time in loop
    $reviews = DB::table('reviews')->whereGame_id($game->id)->paginate(3);
}
```

So, every time there is a new value is being set to `$review` but it should be an array and that's why you should declare an empty array before the loop like this

```
$reviews = []; // or array();
foreach ($games as $game) {
    $reviews[] = DB::table('reviews')->whereGame_id($game->id)->paginate(3);
}
```

So, you'll get an array in the `$review` variable.

Regarding your error message `Undefined variable: reviews`, it's not defined and it could be because `if($input && $input != '')` condition doesn't match or `$games` got nothing, so, try to debug step by step your code, at first make sure that execution control is being entered inside `if` by making `dd($input)` statement inside `if` and then if it outputs anything then make sure `$games` is not null/false by making a `dd($games)` statement after the games query.

You can change the code snippet to this

```
$input = Input::get('title');
if($input) {
    $games = DB::table('games')->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$input%")->get();
    if($games) {
        $reviews = []; // or array();
        foreach ($games as $game) {
            $reviews[] = DB::table('reviews')->whereGame_id($game->id)->paginate(3);
        }
        return View::make('search', compact('reviews', 'input', 'games'));
    }
}
// return a 404 (not found) or something like this or whatever, when nothing found
```

Comment: I can not use the `$reviews->links()` method to get the paginator. I get the following error, because $reviews is now a non-object: `Call to a member function links() on a non-object`. Ive tried to solve this problem by just converting it in the search.blade.php file to an object, like this `$object = (object) $reviews`, but then it says: `Call to undefined method stdClass::links() `

Comment: Because `$reviews` is not a `paginator` instance, it's an array of `paginator` instances. First `paginator` instance is `$reviews[0]`.

Comment: In your view each `$review` (inside `foreach` loop) is an instance of `paginator`.

Comment: okay, so I've put it inside of the foreach loop. now i dont get any errors anymore when viewing the second page of the pagination, but still an empty page :( I'Ve just copied and pasted your snippet, changed the search view, and the other codes are like before